# how to send values to server in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, server

i want to send value to server ,i am getting message as values inserted but at the time of fetching value is null,
code sample.

```
-(void)requestReturnedData:(NSData *)data{ //activated when data is returned
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];
        output.text = dictionary.JSONString; 

        value1TextField.text =[dictionary objectForKey:@"productDescription"] ;
        NSLog(@"val1",value1TextField.text);

    value2TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productId"];
     value3TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productImageUrl"];
     value4TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productName"];
     value5TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productPrice"];
     value6TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productRating"];
    value7TextField.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"productReviews"];

    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
-(void)getTest{
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@" http://www.mobdevapp.com/iphapi/getProductDetail.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"getValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

    //selects what task the server will perform

    //initialize an NSURLConnection  with the request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }

}

-(void)postTest{

    //build up the request that is to be sent to the server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobdevapp.com/iphapi/ProductDetail.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];

    //create data that will be sent in the post
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [dictionary setValue: @"" forKey:@"productDescription"];

    [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:@"productId"];
    [dictionary setValue: @"" forKey:@"productImageUrl"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:@"productName"];
    [dictionary setValue: @"" forKey:@"productPrice"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:@"productRating"];
    [dictionary setValue:@"" forKey:@"productReviews"];

    //serialize the dictionary data as json
    NSData *data = [[dictionary copy] JSONValue];

    [request setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }

}`
```

so that *nslog value is null* ,guide me 
how i send value?????

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDataDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    NSLog(@"serverURL : %@", [serverURL absoluteString]);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:serverURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    // create Asynchronous connection
    NSURLConnection * urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (urlConnection)
        self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Comment: First you convert your Dictionary into NSData  using NSJSONSerialization and then you post complete data in HTTPBody

Comment: in which method do i convert dictionary?

Comment: first line is convert Dictionary to NSData 

requestDataDict  replace this by your dictionary

Comment: if you want to convert again NSData to Dictionary then

      NSMutableDictionary * responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];